# Remove all non-alphanumeric characters, but keep diacritics (accents) and - (dash)

Tags: ruby, regex

I want to remove anything that is:

1. Not alphanumeric (but keep UTF characters é and ã, etc...)
2. Not -

I tried this

```
string.gsub! /\W\D/, ''
```

But this removes accents.

```
"héllo3".gsub /\W\D/, '' #=> hllo3
```

I tried `\P{Alnum}` but this removes dashes.

I need something like...

```
"héllo - there - 1".gsub /regex/ #=> héllo-there-1
```

Here's a Rubular: http://rubular.com/r/RjWwdNka8S

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The obvious answer seems to work.

```
[^-\p{Alnum}]
```

specifies a character which is neither a dash nor a member of the `Alnum` class.

Demo: http://rubular.com/r/pYm9hViNHz

Comment: Excellent answer! I didn't know about the `Alnum` class.

Comment: @Rafa see [here](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Regexp.html#class-Regexp-label-Character+Properties)